# Synchronous resize and upload using graphicsmagick

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I am trying to make resizing of a photo and uploading to a server synchronous. I believe the key will be making the stream function synchronous.

```
function upload(photo, newname, size, cb) {
  gm(request(photo))
  .resize(size[0], size[1])
  .stream(function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      var buf = new Buffer('');
      stdout.on('data', function(data) {
          buf = Buffer.concat([buf, data]);
      });
      stdout.on('end', function(data) {
        var data = {
            Bucket: config.s3_bucket_photos,
            Key: newname,
            Body: buf,
            ACL: 'public-read', 
            ContentType: "image/jpeg"
        };
        uploadToServerSynchronous(data, cb);
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you help explain what you're trying to accomplish by making it synchronous?

Answer (score 3):

It's **not good** to do **sync operations** in NodeJS - it stops processing event queue while Your sync method ends it's work.

As I understand You name "**synchronous**" things that **has callbacks**.

How about **converting stream to promise**?

```
const downloadAndResizePhotoByUrl = (photoUrl, size) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    gm(request(photoUrl))
      .resize(size[0], size[1])
      .streamFn((error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if(error) return reject(error);

        let buffer = Buffer.from('');
        stdout.on('data', data => {
          buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, data]);
        });
        stdout.on('end', () => resolve(buffer));
        stdout.on('error', error => reject(error));
      });

  });
}

const uploadPhotoFromUrlToS3 = async (photoUrl, uploadAs, size, cb) => {
  try {

    const data = await downloadAndResizePhotoByUrl(photoUrl, size);

    uploadToServerSynchronous(
      {
        Bucket: config.s3_bucket_photos,
        Key: uploadAs,
        Body: Buffer.from(data),
        ACL: 'public-read', 
        ContentType: "image/jpeg"
      }, 
      cb
    );
  } 
  catch (error) {
    cb(error);
  } 
}
```

Comment: This code does not seems to work. Function "on" is available on "stdout" variable but not object returned by the "resize" function (gm object).

Comment: @user1217406 ops ) forgot about stream method

Comment: @user1217406 understood, it was scope issue. Try my updated answer